# iPad address bar is translucent instead of white?

Tags: html, css

When I view my website on an iPad, the address bar is translucent and the content can be seen behind the address bar, (the browser menu bar, where you put the website, etc).

I am trying to make the address bar a solid/opaque colour so the content isn't behind.
I have tried similar to

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">  
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

or

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
```

But neither change anything.

Is there way to stop the content showing behind the address bar or is this a user setting on the device?

Thanks

Comment: It's the design of the address bar (and other OS components) and has been so for many years already.